# DynamoDB Is there any way to generate unique autoID?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new in the DynamoDB Lamda I am following some tutorial but I need to is there any way to generate autoid in Dynamodb ?

This is my lambda function as you see i pass the QuestionID as hardcoded I need to know is there any way to create unique for this? 
I think i can do link Math random function with a timestamp but really want to know the better option for this to create it.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        Item: {
            "QuestionID": {
                S: "dasf787af8safa"
            },
            "Would": {
                S: "2ass8"
            },
            "Rather": {
                S: "asda"
            },
            "wouldClick": {
                N: "2"
            },
            "ratherClick": {
                N: "2"
            }
        },
        TableName: "Would-You-Rather"
    };
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What do you think of uuid4? Something like this one https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid

Comment: Thanks, i see the link and found something good that the request-id is the uuid4. So now i am using context.awsRequestId as my id so its good method or sometimes request ids can same?

Comment: I don't think request ids could be the same, probably AWS is using something similar to uuid4 to generate them.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer, take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't come out of the box.
If you want a numeric PK you can exploit something like this:

```js
client.update_item(
      TableName='JiraTable', Key={
         'PK': { 'S': 'PROJECT#my-project'
         'SK': { 'S': 'PROJECT#my-project' }
    }, }
  UpdateExpression="SET #count = #count + :incr",
  ExpressionAttributeNames={ "#count": "IssueCount", }, 
  ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ":incr": { "N": "1" } 
  },
  ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW'
)

current_count = resp['Attributes']['IssueCount']['N']

resp = client.put_item(
  TableName='JiraTable',
  Item={
    'PK': { 'S': 'PROJECT#my-project' },
    'SK': { 'S': f"ISSUE#{current_count}"},
    'IssueTitle': {'S':'Build DynamoDB data model'}
  }
)
```

If you want to use UUIDs, and you are really sure about it, I suggest you [KSUID](https://segment.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-the-uuid/). KSUIDs are unique identifiers that include a timestamp in the beginning. This allows for chronological ordering as well as uniqueness.

Nevertheless, do you really want to use this type of data as your partition key?
You should exploit some data more informative, like an email, otherwise you lose an index useful for your access patterns.